# Get a random file from a folder and add it to an iTunes playlist

Tags: file, random, applescript, itunes, playlists

I have looked at some answers which tell me how to get random files from folders, and some which can deal with iTunes playlists. Haven't been able to put these together.

What I'm looking for is a way (I was thinking in AppleScript) of getting the 200 songs in my Folk playlist folder on my hard drive, randomly selecting 20 of those songs, and then adding them to an iTunes playlist.

I am aware smart playlists can kind of do this, but I want to do it as much outside of iTunes as possible, because a lot of my music is in folders and not on iTunes per se.

I'd be really grateful of any help with:

1. Getting 20 random files from a folder
   And
2. Then pushing them into a playlist.

I did wonder if there was some way I could get the number of files in per cent (20% of the files in Folk), but it's not really a deal breaker!

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me!

Tardy

Comment: As far as I know you can't add a file to an iTunes playlist which is not in the iTunes database, I mean you have to import the files into iTunes anyway

Comment: Vadian, I was thinking of maybe using an automator action to import the files into iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script you're looking for. I leave the first answer because it could also be useful for others.

```
property RList : "my random list" -- name of the random list
property ListGenres : {"Rock", "Pop", "Soundtrack", "Jazz"} -- your list of genres
property NumPerGenre : {3, 2, 5, 4} -- the number of songs per genre

tell application "iTunes"
if exists user playlist RList then -- check if the playlsit exists or not
    delete tracks of user playlist RList -- delete all current tracks of the play list
    repeat while (number of tracks of playlist RList) > 0
        delay 0.1 -- wait for the library to clear out, because iTunes is asynchronous !
    end repeat
else -- creation of the play list
    set MyPlayList to make new user playlist with properties {name:RList}
end if

repeat with I from 1 to (count of ListGenres) -- loop per genre
    set ListTracks to (tracks whose genre is (item I of ListGenres))
    repeat with J from 1 to (item I of NumPerGenre) -- loop to add x tracks per genre
        set TheTrack to item (random number from 1 to (count of ListTracks)) of ListTracks
        duplicate TheTrack to playlist RList
    end repeat -- loop for all tracks per genre
end repeat -- loop by Genre
play playlist RList -- start to play !  
end tell
```

I've put many comments to make it clear (I hope). In this example, I have 4 genres, and I will get 3 songs of the first genre, 2 songs of the second genre, ...and so on. you can change these properties, as long as the list of genre count same number of items as list of numpergenre.

Unfortunately, since iTunes 11, the shuffle attribute can't be set via script, you must set it manually in iTunes to play the list randomly (it can be set once for all)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Can I ask how you learn ask those variable names and commands? I've tried using the AppleScript dictionary, but wondered if there's a book I could get with all those in rather than using search engines to find one bit here, another bit there, etc.?

Comment: Just ran it in applescript (not as an app), and seems to accomplish the job, but leaves Applescript spinning and have to force quit. Should I put a 'giving up after' line in there somewhere?

Comment: It could be due to huge number of tracks. My iTunes counts only about 7000, and it's OK. I never tested (and can't) with 20000 tracks. if you run the script from Editor, display events/results at bottom of the window and add some log instruction lines at different places to see where issue is. A log instruction is like log "trace step 1". Looking to bottom window of script Editor, you will see all the traces, one by one,  up to the point it blocks. doing so, you will see where it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

to play tracks, you must first import them in iTunes as Vadian said. better to import them in play list (easier to delete after). the script bellow does that :

```
set MyRatio to 0.2 -- the % of files randomly selected over the total file of the selected folder
set MyFolder to choose folder "select folder with your musics"
tell application "Finder" to set MyList to every file of MyFolder

-- build the random list
set SongList to {}
set MaxCount to (MyRatio * (count of MyList)) as integer
set MyCount to 0
repeat until MyCount = MaxCount
set MyItem to random number from 1 to (count of MyList)
set NewFile to (item MyItem of MyList) as string
if NewFile is not in SongList then
    copy NewFile to the end of SongList
    set MyCount to MyCount + 1
end if
end repeat

-- add the files to iTunes new playlist
tell application "iTunes"
set MyPlayList to make new user playlist with properties {name:"my Import"}
repeat with I from 1 to count of SongList
    add ((item I of SongList) as alias) to MyPlayList
end repeat
play MyPlayList -- start to play the play list
end tell
```

Comment: That is brilliant, pbell. I really appreciate the effort you've put in - and I'm sure I can use that code to my own ends with a bit of tweaking!

Comment: The only thing I'm not sure about, is: does it look recursively in the folder, or just on the top level? Really would like it to dig deeper.

Comment: change the 3rd line by adding "entire contents" : tell application "Finder" to set MyList to every file of entire contents of MyFolder whose name extension is in {"mp3", "aif"}. You must complete the list with your possible file's extensions.

Comment: Thanks so much! All your comments appreciated. Definitely solved my problem.

Comment: I realise I am being a pain, but I tried to fiddle with the code so I could make it into an app which runs through a load of folders and gets a different number from each, but I fell at the first hurdle.  I changed the code so it starts:  tell application "Finder" to set MyList to every file of entire contents of alias "Macintosh HD:General Music:02 Rock:02E Rock 2010-2020:" whose name extension is in {"mp3", "m4a", "aif", "mp4"}.  It seems to be timing out before getting to the random list stage. Any idea how I can get it to get 15 tracks from my Rock 2010-2020 folder, then 5 from another?

Comment: The time out could be that you have too many files in folders/sub folders. an idea could be to get random sub folder, and in this sub folder  get random files (each time less items), but to help you more, please explain your folder/sub folder/song structure. Also other way to look at it is to understand why you do not want to move all them into iTunes and make the random from here.

Comment: I really like to have all the folders organised my way, not iTunes'. I organise by genre and subgenre, and sometimes there is overlap of genres within those folders, sometimes not. The main reason for the question I'm asking is to try and restrict it to certain folders, which is much easier when you have, say, 11 folders to tell it to search in. I also don't like having all that music in iTunes - I have lots of things I don't want to search through on a casual basis.

Comment: If this is too taxing on the system and will cause timeouts, maybe there is a way you could suggest doing it within iTunes?

Comment: If the number on the left is the number of songs, and the genre is on the right, I would like to be able to call up at random a selection from the folders that includes a mix such as:
2 Classical  <br/>
3 Reggae  
3 Modern Jazz  
4 Folk  
5 Jazz  
6 Rock 1970s  
6 Rock 1980s  
8 Popular Song  
15 Soul & Rap  
15 Rock 50s-60s  
15 Rock 2000s  
18 Rock 2010s

Comment: And I tend to organise them like this:
General Music > Rock > Rock 1980s > The Smiths > Albums (& songs not on albums loose)

Comment: in iTunes preferences, advanced panel, you can deselect the box "leave iTunes organise your files" and "copy in iTunes Media folder...". doing so, I think you can leave your files and folders where they are, and still have them visible in iTunes. then you can ask random play in iTunes directly without script.

Comment: Thanks pbell. But how would I achieve a ratio of tunes - e.g. 2% Classical, 3% Rock - or even just 2 classical pieces, 3 rock pieces, 4 jazz etc.? Is it just best to do it all through a smart folder system?